# kubectl throwing segmentation fault

Tags: docker, segmentation-fault, virtual-machine, containers, kubernetes

I have started playing with kubernetes. I followed the guide to set it up locally via minikube. I have perfectly managed to configure I am facing a weird issue. Whenever I try running some command using kubectl I get **segmentation fault (core dumped)**. Even when I tried accessing the directory 'kubectl', it threw the same error.
*I have searched around the internet and have tried different solutions, but no luck*

Comment: What version of kubectl are you running? And is it the appropriate build for your host architecture?

Comment: @RobertBailey v.1.2.4 and yes, the host architecture is suitable.

Comment: @RobertBailey What I am guessing is it has something to do with permissions and I accidentally messed them up and now it's throwing me segmentation error. I tried running **kubectl run hello-minikube --image=gcr.io/google_containers/echoserver:1.4 --hostport=8000 --port=8080** after **minikube start** and it threw me with a permission error. I chmod the directory and it started throwing me with this error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where did you install kubectl from? What's the output of `kubectl version`?

Comment: @dlorenc https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.2.4/bin/darwin/amd64/kubectl

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve this issue by removing all kubectl configurations and reinstalling it. Make sure after downloading, the binary is executable and move it into your PATH:

```
$ chmod +x kubectl
$ mv kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

Comment: Segmentation Fault can come if the `kubectl` binary is not downloaded properly. I got this error bcoz it is 20% downloaded and I got segmentation error.

Answer (score 3):

Operation system: **Mac OSX High Sierra**

I had the same problem when I download using the link below:

```
curl -Lo kubectl http://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.3.0/bin/darwin/386/kubectl && chmod +x kubectl && sudo mv kubectl /usr/local/bin/
```

- Segmentation fault: 11

I could solve it when I installed the kubectl using brew:

```
brew install kubectl
```

I hope it can help.

Comment: Same error for me after using this method

Comment: Using brew install command helped me solving this issue.